# Keep responses from redis server unique to each connected client

Tags: vb.net, redis

I have a problem with a redis connection.

My clients connect to the redis server and there is async function which listens to reponses from the redis server.

Now the problem is a single client is also getting all the responses the is meant for the other client also.

Is there a way to keep these responses unqiue per client.

Here is the connection code:

```
Dim clientsManager As New PooledRedisClientManager ("ip:port")
  redisPubSub = New RedisPubSubServer(clientsManager, paramarrayvalue) With   { _
.OnMessage = Async Sub(channel, msg) Await OnMessage(msg), _
.OnError = Sub(ex) OnError(ex) 
        }.Start()
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Redis pub/sub functionality, *all* clients subscribed to a particular channel will receive any message published to the channel.  If you want messages to only go to a single client, you will have to create a separate channel for that client.

Comment: that is being done the channel gets created uses the user id in the channel to make it unqiue